# L'espressione "si fa fredda" è italiano standard?

Tags: word-usage

In una pizzeria a Barcellona ho letto la scritta seguente:

> L'amore può aspettare, ma la pizza no che **si fa fredda**.

Mi è sembrata molto curiosa perché non avevo mai letto né sentito l'espressione "si fa fredda". Io invece avrei detto "si raffredda".

Si tratta d'italiano standard oppure è una locuzione che si usa solo in alcune regioni d'Italia? Se è così, in quali regioni è solito esprimersi in questo modo?

Comment: Normalmente da dove vengo io si dice *si fredda*. *Si fa fredda* non l'avevo mai sentita ma è sicuramente grammaticalmente corretta.

Answer (score 3):

Grammaticalmente è corretta, ma non è italiano standard. Suona molto colloquiale/dialettale. Io sono pugliese (provincia di Lecce) e qui ogni tanto si sente dire così. In italiano standard si dice "si raffredda/si fredda/diventa fredda".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Non conoscevo "si fredda" e, dal commento di @Denis, avevo pensato fosse qualcosa del nord Italia.

Comment: @Charo [Freddare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/freddare/) :)

Comment: Non direi proprio che sia colloquiale, né dialettale. Non è una frase fatta, ma rientra perfettamente negli usi potenziali del verbo fare: “In genere, _farsi_, divenire: _s’è fatta una bella ragazza_; _come si son fatti grandi!_; _farsi cattolico_; _farsi scuro in volto_ (anche del tempo: _s’è fatto buio_; _s’è fatto giorno_; _s’è fatto tardi_)” ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2)).